# Specify or Change Plot Order on Scatter Plot with Tibco Spotfire

Tags: scatter-plot, spotfire

Is there a way to alter the native 'plot order' in Spotfire?  Effectively, I want to control which data is plotted in front.

My current issue is that data is being hidden by an overlapping data set, and I want to change which data set is plotted in front.

I have tried changing the column order which controls the 'colorby' filter, and Google has yielded no help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out one work-around:

1) Create column with numerical values corresponding to the plot order, with the 'data in front' having being '1', and increasing for each layer going back;

2) Enable the 'size-by' filter, and select this new column;

3) Manually program the min/max limits to be '1' and '1';

4) Profit;

Answer (score 0):

Just to share my taking, I advance your idea a little to create a calculated column (to the underline data table of the plot) known as "Plot_Order" so that I can use python to change the Expression of the calculated column on the fly to control the plot order based on users' selection. Something like below:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import CalculatedColumn

#Note: Some codes here to do the Expression, such as to calculate the plot order based on marking of another table plot, etc, like below pseudo codes 

'''
calExpression="if(a??=b??, 1, 2)"
...

calculatedColumn=myTable.Columns["Plot_Order"].As[CalculatedColumn]()
calculatedColumn.Expression=calExpression
```